# Error in external code: Argument exception unhandled

Tags: c#, exception

I am getting an Argument exception unhandled error in external code `Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'MODES' Key being added 'MODES'` And the source code isn't available as it isn't my code. 
I am confused because I am not adding anything to a dictionary in my code.

I am listening to suspend and resume events and the error happens on resume (I think). How do I fix this?

This is the code I added which started causing the error:

```
private void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(Object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("RECIEVED SIGNAL: " + e.Mode);
        if (e.Mode.Equals(PowerModes.Suspend))   //computer going to sleep
            {
            if (bots != null && bots.Count > 0)
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string,irc> b in bots)
                    {
                    b.Value.disconnect();
                    }
            }

        else if (e.Mode.Equals(PowerModes.Resume))   //computer waking up
            {
            if (bots != null && bots.Count > 0)
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, irc> b in bots)
                    {
                    b.Value.connect();
                    }
            }
        }
```

screenshot of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lm1S.png

Comment: where you add items to `bots`?

Comment: I am sure its not because of bots, because that's not external code, and it would have shown me the source for it, and this error did not happen before adding the above code which does not modify the bots dictionary. I'll reproduce this error again with "Just my code" turned off.

Comment: I got a dis-assembly on System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert pointing to `000004e8  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esi+10h] `

Comment: I've given up getting a response to this and think it may be a bug in the .NET libraries. As an extreme test I've enclosed my entire code in a try/catch and still get the error, further proving that it is not my code. As a work around I can keep track of power state myself.